# What is the best way to loop through string and insert into mysql column?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, insert, explode

I have a variable which displays the following string:

`$item_value = itemOne,itemTwo,itemThree`

I would like to take this string and have insert each item as a separate row entry for a single column.  Additionally, I need it to insert an auto increment key value for each entry.  So to complete this example, here is what I would want the mysql table to look like when complete:

`ID || item_value || comments`

`----------------------------------------`

`1   ||  itemOne   || --------------`

`2   ||  itemTwo   || --------------`

`3   || itemThree || --------------`

My feeling is that I need to explode the string around the comma and then insert it into the table.  I have attempted this but am having some issues getting each item as separate row entries.  Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: use explode() and foreach ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should split them up and give the option for insertion in the db:

```
<?php
$item_value = 'itemOne,itemTwo,itemThree';
$item_array = explode(",",$item_value);

foreach($item_array as $key => $value){
    // insert into the db here
    $query = "INSERT INTO table_name set item_value = '".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."', ID = '".($key + 1)."'";
    // however you choose to connect and insert into the database goes here :)
}
?>
```

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 2):

For the auto-increment i suggest letting the database handle it, for mysql just declare it with AUTO_INCREMENT on the id field, for postgres you can set the data type to serial, as for separating each line use the php explode function

here's a little example

```
<?php
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
  $query = "INSERT into my_table (item_value) VALUES (?)";

  $data = 'itemOne,itemTwo,itemThree,itemFour';
  $st = $dbh->prepare($query);

  foreach(explode(',', $data) as $r) {
    // user array($r) for php 5.3 or lower
    $st->execute([$r]);
  }
```

This uses PDO which is the recommended method for handling database connections